# How do I uninstall airtel 4g dongle

Tags: uninstall

I installed 4g dongle on Ubuntu 14.04 ... but somehow the `airtel` program is not working.  I would like to uninstall it, but I couldn't find the program in the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there isn't a program through which to configure the 4G dongle.

#### To enable/disable Airtel 4G dongle

Paste the following into a **.html** file:

```
<form action = "http://192.168.0.1/goform/goform_set_cmd_process" method = "post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="goformId" value="CONNECT_NETWORK" checked style="display:none;">
 <BUTTON name="submit" type="submit"> Connect </BUTTON>
</form>

<form action = "http://192.168.0.1/goform/goform_set_cmd_process" method = "post">
 <input type="checkbox" name="goformId" value="DISCONNECT_NETWORK" checked style="display:none;">
 <BUTTON name="submit" type="submit"> Disconnect </BUTTON>
</form>
```

Save the file and open it with your preferred browser.

Click the `Connect` or `Disconnect` buttons to enable or disable the dongle.